# Wrapping in xul:hbox

Tags: xul, word-wrap, hbox

I have strange problem with XUL layouts.
My current code:

```
<xul:vbox>
  <xul:hbox> .. some elements .. </xul:hbox>
  <xul:hbox>
    <xul:hbox> .. some elements .. </xul:hbox>
    <xul:hbox flex="1">
      <my:button anon-id="btn1" label="Sample button 1"/>
      <my:button anon-id="btn2" label="Sample button 2"/>
      ...
      <my:button anon-id="btnN" label="Sample button N"/>
    </xul:hbox>
    <xul:hbox> .. some elements .. </xul:hbox>
  <xul:hbox>
</xul:vbox>
```

I need to make hbox with buttons resizable, but if buttons doesn't fit in container - it should be wrapped for 2 (or more) lines. Currently, when I shrink browser size - some of buttons hiding behind the right border of window.

`my:button` is box with `display: inline-block;` and some content inside.

I have tried `float: left` on button, `display: block`, `overflow: visibel` and other tricks worked in HTML/CSS.

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `<description>` tag instead of the `<hbox>` surrounding the buttons.